# $(document).width() vs. $('BODY').width() in IE9

Tags: jquery, positioning

I'm working on a type of 'spotlight' plugin that puts four boxes around a target element (top, left, bottom, and right).  Thus, the boxes need to be positioned and sized programmatically.

I've come across an instance where $(document).width() returns a consistent value in Firefox, Chrome, IE7, and IE8, but not in IE9—the value in IE9 is 17px greater than the others.  However, if I switch it up to $('BODY').width() the value becomes consistent in ALL browsers.  Unfortunately, I can't post a fiddle of this because I can't replicate it outside of the development environment.

What might be causing this inconsistency between the body and document width...and ONLY in IE9 (remember, IE7/8 aren't affected)?  I've verified standards mode and the padding/margins are zeroed out for HTML/BODY.

Comment: Having something to do with microsoft implementations of standards always brings trouble...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the extra 17px you experience is the y scrollbar, which you don't normally have in jsfiddle, and counts towards the document but not the body.

Yes this is due to browsers not implementing the box model / standards consistently. Theres not much you can do about it except work arround it.

Comment: I was pretty sure it had something to do with the scrollbar, but wasn't positive since it didn't happen with IE7/8.  So looks like a bug in IE9 then.  Thanks :)